# What could this portion of the 'Information Security Handbook' by John M.D Hunter possibly mean?

Tags: linux, security, passwd, integrity

So I am reading this Information Security Handbook by John M.D. Hunter. I quote two paragraphs of the book below:

"An operating system is usually capable of preventing users from performing illegal operations when the computer system is running normally. Unfortunately there is nothing that software can do to prevent illegal operations taking place when the sytem is not running. The danger is that when the system is "down", another - less secure - system can be used to bypass security features and make unauthorised changes.

By way of example, it is possible to boot up a PC Unix look-alike operating system called Linux from two floppy discs. Once Linux is up and running, the unauthorised user can login as root (the privileged user) and then mount the discs of the operating system normally resident on the hard disc. Then it is a trivial matter to alter the security critical files such as `etc/passwd`. When the legitimate version of the operating system is run up, it will be blissfully unaware of the unauthosized changes made to its files".

I attempt severally to understand this portion of his book, but no luck :(. Any help in understanding really welcome.

Comment: The last sentence from quotation is wrong, there are instruments to reveal if file is altered (even postfactum)

Comment: What part is confusing you? The text seems perfectly clear, so you will need to point out the parts you don't understand.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, except that in the basic case, whatever information the OS uses to verify the files can _also_ be spoofed by the OS booted from the floppy (/CD/DVD/flash drive/whatever). Stuff like TPM chips might help there, but the quote says "there is nothing that _software_ can do", and that's still true.

Comment: @ilkkachu, if the checksums are online, on writable media. What about read-only NFS, CD?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, then they just edit the program that reads and compares the checksums...

Comment: @terdon OP here,,,, if I should mount a hard drive containing say Kali Linux onto a computer that runs an Ubuntu and try to alter the passwd file on the Kali,,, does that mean that user accounts on the altered passwd file would be able to login to the system?  i.e., if I should take the Kali (now with altered passwd) and boot it normally on a computer, does that mean that I can log in normally (into the Kali) with a record that exists on the altered passwd file? That's how I see what the passage says,,, and imo, it sounds too good to be true. Is it?

Comment: @RomeoNinov,,,, well I guess instruments you refer to would be based on hashing, checksums. I guess your comment would apply if some conscious effort had been applied to hash the files (e.g, passwd file) on the system before the attack. If not, a postfactum reveal wouldn't be feasible

Comment: @Jake yes, exactly. That's why it is a well known saying in the infosec world that if an attacker has physical access to a computer, then that computer is by definition considered compromised.

Comment: @terdon, oh wow, thanks. Next thing would be me trying that out myself to see how it goes :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that *the operating system* can't prevent a person from physically accessing the system, booting an externally provided operating system, and in that way accessing/altering privileged information.

Comment: The only sensible solution is encryption.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, for personal data.  But that's not part of the question. Neither does the book say anything about what the other OS is or is not, just that Linux is an example of a small operating system that potentially could be used to access sensitive information when the native OS is not running.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, encryption _and authentication_. They're not the same, and especially with full-disk encryption, adding authentication is a bit of a nuisance, since it changes the amount of data stored, turning nice power-of-two blocks into not so nicely sized blocks which don't match the sizes most storage expects...

Comment: And as @ilkkachu seem to have loosely mentioned, an FDE should be able to circumvent an isolated accessing/altering I believe

Comment: @Jake Absolutely. The question was about text comprehension though, not about what technology to employ on the affected system (which may not even be a Unix system for all that we know).